# Is there an implementation of the idea described in "Detecting NearDuplicates for Web Crawling"

Tags: algorithm, duplicates, similarity

The paper: http://www2007.org/papers/paper215.pdf

I am just wondering are there any implementations of chapter 3 of that paper. I mean querying among large datasets, NOT only the simhash (it's easy to find simhash implementations).

Thanks~

Comment: If you propose the problem at http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ probably you will end with a 250-byte perl implementation for free. It is a joke.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [one](http://d3s.mff.cuni.cz/~holub/sw/shash/) though I haven't tested it works. The good thing its opensource.

Comment: I've already found this. I mean I am looking for the implementation of chapter 3 in that paper. But still thank you~

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem in `Data mining` and `similarity search`.  There are numerous articles describing how that can be done, and scaling up to massive amounts of data.

I have an implementation ([github : mksteve, clustering](https://github.com/mksteve/Clustering), with some comments about it in my [blog](http://hearnden.org.uk/techlog/?p=16)) of [wikipedia : Metric tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tree)  .  This requires that the measures you are making meet the triangle inequality  ([wikipedia : Metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space).  That is that the metric distance from item A to item C is less than or equal to the distance A to B + the distance B to C.

Given that inequality, it is possible to trim the search space, so only sub-trees which may overlap with your target area, are searched.  Without that feature being true (metric-space).

Possibly the number of bits of difference in the simhash would be a metric space.

The general usage of these datasets, is alluded to in the document when it mentions mapReduce, which is generally run on a `hadoop cluster`.  The processing nodes are each given a sub-set of the data, and find a set of target matches from their local datasets.  These are then combined to give a fully ordered list of similar items.

There are some papers (unsure of references) which allude to using m-trees in a cluster, where different parts of the search space are given to different clusters, but I am not sure whether the hadoop infra-structure would support using such a high level abstraction.